# Holding down the power button

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

When pc freezes,due to malware or virus,which is a better option?Holding the power button or Restart button?in terms of hardware safety(motherboard,PSU).
I have installed KIS'17 today.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a machine hit by malware, such as WannaCry, you want to stop that operation as fast as possible - the easiest way to do this successfully is power the machine off via the power button, or even better - pull the cord. This is because some power buttons may send signals to the O/S indicating it's shutting down and you don't want to give the malware any 'heads up' as to what is happening.

Once you've done this, you'll want to analyse the system safely from another system which either can't be infected, or where you've taken precautions to ensure infection is not possible.

**If you used the restart button, you may accidently reboot the computer causing more problems.**